# jQuery addClass - content appears, then disappears

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So Im creating something that only displays the navbar and when one of the items is clicked it displays the content here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar').bind('click', function(){
         $('.page-location').addClass('visible');
    });
});
```

Problem is that once i click on the item the content appears and then disappears. Could someone help me fix this issue or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Any help appreciated

Edit HTML Code:

```
<header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="content">
                <img src="<?php echo $dir; ?>/img/logo-orange.png">
                <h1>Live Inspired</h1>
                <h5>Website Coming Soon</h5>
                <h6>Summer of 2016</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Birmingham</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Birmingham, Aston</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Manchester</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Leeds</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Edinburgh</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you share the html code?

Comment: Please generate a jsfiddle

Comment: yeah give me two secs

Comment: why is your `div` block inside `header` tag ? Also, in your HTML example, i cannot find any elements with class `page-location`. Maybe incomplete HTML part ?

Comment: And the code for page-location class please.

Comment: Sorry Figured Out my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was being a bad developer by using .on instead of .bind fixed my issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar').on('click', function(){
         $('.page-location').addClass('visible');
    });
});
```

Thanks too all who offered there help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard jQuery `.show();` function to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar').on('click', function(){
         $('.page-location').show();
    });
});
```

This will show your class when clicked

Comment: This doesn't work, Because I have multiple things that need to be shown and some that don't .show() will show all elements

Comment: `.show();` doesn't show all elements it will do exactly the same as adding the visible class, if you've solved it then just carry on the way you have done it, it all works the same anyways